# Show the series $\sum \frac{x^n}{(2n)!}$ is covergent for all $x\in\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

Textbook power series problem I thought.
Let $a_n = \frac{x^n}{(2n)!}$ and apply the limit comparison test.
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{x^{n+1}(2n)!}{x^n(2(n+1))!}| = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{x}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}|=|\frac{x}{2}|$$
But from here I know the series $\sum a_n$ converges if $|x|\lt 2$ and moreover we find the two boundary points yield converging sequences, hence $\sum a_n$ converges if $|x| \le 2$.

But.... I'm proving the sequence converges for *all* of $x\in \mathbb R$.

What am I missing?

Comment: You simply made a mistake in the last step for the limit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By ratio test we have

$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = \left|\frac{x^{n+1}(2n)!}{x^n(2(n+1))!}\right| =|x| \frac{1}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}\to 0$$